# session timeout across proxy apache weblogic & java app

Tags: session

How do I distinguish session timeouts between a Proxy server, Apache , a weblogic server & an Application layer. I understand how session alive time is managed at different layers individually , but I am trying to understand how this session is managed across these different layers.

I can control the session time thru my Java App using Jscripting. If I was to set my session timeout for 30 mins then would this also allow 30 mins in weblogic layer  & apache (http) layer and at the proxy servers ?